# FFMPEG using wrong arguements when refering to image files

Tags: windows, image, batch-file, ffmpeg

I am creating a bat file that will use FFMPEG to convert Real Media files to .MP4 files. I am looping though the current folder and finding files with the .rm extension adding several pictures to the video files to create a slide show effect in the final product.

With this code here it works except it only shows one static image:

```
for %%a in ("*.rm") do ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/5 -i "img00.jpg" -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 48k -b:v 16k "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
```

With this code it should show a series of photos. However it does not:

```
for %%a in ("*.rm") do ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/5 -i "img%02d.jpg" -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 48k -b:v 16k "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
```

I get this error when I run the second piece of code:

> Could find no file with with path 'imgC:\Data\RealtoMP\FFMPEG_JPG\ffmpegA48V16_AudOnly' and index in the range 0-4
>   imgC:\Data\RealtoMP\FFMPEG_JPG\ffmpegA48V16_AudOnly: No such file or directory

It appears to me that it is somehow instead of getting the range argument like it should, it's injecting the path to the file that I am running. Any ideas of what is causing this?

EDIT:

I fixed my problem by escaping the `%02` with another %. The result is `%%02` for it to act correctly in the script.

Comment: [See the documentation for a complete feature list](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%0` in a batch file will expand to the path to the batch file.

In your second code sample you have a `"img%02d.jpg"` -- that will expand to `"img` + the path to your batch file + `2d.jpg"`.

When you can't figure out what a batch file is doing (especially when you have long command lines), I find it helpful to `echo` the command line instead of (or as well as) calling it directly.  That makes it much easier to see the problem yourself.  For example:

```
for %%a in ("*.rm") do (
    echo ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/5 -i "img%02d.jpg" -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 48k -b:v 16k "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
)
```

That prints out the command line instead of calling it directly, and you would immediately see where the command line is not what you expect it to be. Tweak the code until the output looks right, then remove the `echo`.